# Why does $\exists \ y \ \forall\ x\ Q(x, y) \implies \forall\ x\ \exists\ y\ Q(x, y)$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Why does $\exists \ y \ \forall\  x\  Q(x, y) \implies \forall\ x\ \exists\ y\ Q(x, y)$? Is it possible to prove this?

Answer (score 2):

1) $\exists y\forall xQ(x,y)$.

2) $\forall xQ(x,b)$.

3) $Q(x,b)$.

4) $\exists y Q(x,y)$.

5) $\forall x\exists yQ(x,y)$.

Comment: How did you go from 4) to 5) ?

Comment: The variable $x$ is not bound.

Comment: OK! Even though I am not the OP thanks so much!

Comment: I don't understand. This seems to imply the converse of the statement as well, which is wrong. In other words, for your solution, why can't one go from Step 5 to Step 1?

Comment: Loosely speaking, one cannot split $\exists yQ(x,y)$ to be $\exists y$ and $Q(x,y)$ to put $\forall x$ in the middle, the whole $\exists yQ(x,y)$ is a bundle.

Comment: I mean, one should view $P(x)=\exists yQ(x,y)$.

Comment: But $\forall x R(x,y)$ implies $\forall x\exists y R(x,y)$, this is going through, the universal quantifier is much more stronger. In general, one cannot insert $\forall$ after $\exists$.

Comment: Whether $\forall x R(x,y)$ implies $\forall x\forall y R(x,y)$ depends what is the role of the $y$ in $\forall x R(x.y)$, if this $y$ is realised by a previous  $\exists$, then it fails. But if this $y$ is free, then it goes through.

Comment: Back to the $\exists y Q(x,y)$, the safest thing you can do is that to imply $\exists y\exists x Q(x,y)$.

Comment: And keep in mind that $\exists y\exists x Q(x,y)=\exists x\exists y Q(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine an infinitely sized chessboard.

$\exists y \forall x ~Qxy$ says "at least one row of the board is completely inhabited".

$\forall x \exists y ~Qxy$ says "in each column, there is at least one inhabited spot".

The first implies the second because if there is a completely inhabited row, then each column must have at least 1 inhabited spot, that point where the column crosses the row.

Answer (score 0):

Why not proving by contradiction?

Assume this implication doesn't hold, hence $\exists y \forall x Q(x,y)$ and $\lnot \forall x \exists y Q(x,y)$.

Then note that $\lnot\forall x \exists y Q(x,y) \equiv \exists x \forall y \lnot Q(x,y)$. Define $x=:a$ for some element. Then we have $\forall y \lnot Q(a,y)$, in particular $\lnot Q(a,b)$. On the other hand we have $\exists y \forall xQ(x,y)$, we call this $y=:b$. We get $\forall x Q(x,b)$, in particular $Q(a,b)$.

So we have $Q(a,b)$ and $\lnot Q(a,b)$ at the same time, hence our assumption must be wrong.